# Zip .pdf files to limited size(10 MB each zip file) parts in c#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a requirement that in one folder we will be having some .pdf files and i need to zip the files for a limited size(zip file shouldn't be more than 10MB) and it could be any number of zip files.

it would be great if any one does this in c#.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DotNetZip - Calculate final zip size before calling Save(stream) in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815633/dotnetzip-calculate-final-zip-size-before-calling-savestream-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes tried with that but the size is coming wrong

using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zf = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        zf.AddFile(fileNames[i], string.Empty);

                        

                    
                    }
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    zip.Save(ms);

                    byte[] fileData = ms.ToArray();
                    var fileSize = fileData.Length;
                }